# How can i search using name which consists of first,middle and last name in laravel 5.3??

Tags: php, html, laravel

/* ErrorException in CoachController.php line 135: Undefined offset: 1 */

```
 else if(!empty($request->coach_name))
        {
           $name=explode(' ',$request->coach_name);
           $fname=$name[0];
           $mname=$name[1];
           $lname=$name[2];
           $coach=Tbl_Coach::select('tbl__coaches.*')
                ->where('tbl__coaches.coach_fname','=',$fname) 
                ->where('tbl__coaches.coach_mname','=',$mname)
                ->where('tbl__coaches.coach_lname','=',$lname)
                ->get();
            return view('sport_organization_user.coach_master.index',compact('coach'));
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: I am getting an error as 'ErrorException in CoachController.php line 135:
Undefined offset: 1' when i enter 'Sangay' in input field and search. If i enter 'Sangay w Lhamo' in the input field then i can search using the above code. I don't know exactly what's wrong with my logic and how should i search using name in laravel 5.3??

Comment: Then read the duplicate question. Your error is "undefined offset" and it's not the first time someone has asked it on Stack Overflow. If the error happens when you type in "Sangay" then it's pretty obvious why the error occurs. You need to read up on how to debug PHP, and learn how `explode` and arrays work.

Comment: I know that when I enter Sangay then array will have only Sangay at index 0 whereas, index 1 and index 2 will not have any data that's why the above error has occurred. Now, my question is how should i modify my code so, that it can be searchable when I enter Sangay only in the input field. Any help would be appreciated. In other words, how should i assign $mname and $lname according to the explode array results??

Comment: That depends on how you want to design your system. What happens if someone enters the first name or last name only? You could use `->orWhere()` instead of `->where()` to compare the value entered against any of the name fields.

Comment: thank you I will try using in that ways.

Answer (score 0):

i think the array $name is matter of the error! make sure $name[1] $name[2] is exist!